# PHP: Canot include file when implementing class

Tags: php, oop

When i implement interface in my class, autoloader first get interface class with namespace, and include it without problems. But then it get interface class name without namespace, so my autoloader can't include these file and i have error.
My class:

```
namespace model\order;
use lib\model as Lib;
class Bitgo implements Lib\BitcoinInterface
{

}
```

Autoloader:

```
<?php
Class Autoloader
{
public function __construct()
{
    spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'mainAutoload'));
}

public function mainAutoload ($className)
{
    var_dump(__DIR__);
    if ($className) {
        $fullPath = $this->checkPathExist($className);

        require_once ($fullPath);

        $this->checkClassExist($className);
    }
}

private function checkPathExist($className) {

    $pathClass = str_replace(['_', '\\'], '/', $className);
    $fullPath  = URL_APP  . $pathClass . '.php';

    if (file_exists($fullPath)) {
        return $fullPath;
    }

    $fullPath = strtolower($fullPath);
    if (file_exists($fullPath)) {
        return $fullPath;
    }

    if (SYSTEM_DEBUG_MODE) {
        exit('Error: file not exists - ' . $fullPath);
    }
    $error = 'System error! Please report to email: info@bit-changer.net';
    Lib_logger::saveToLog($error . ' (Path: '.$fullPath.')', LOG_TYPE_ERROR_CRITICAL);
    exit($error);
}

private function checkClassExist($className) {

    if (class_exists($className)) {
        return;
    }

    if (strripos($className, '\\') > 0) {
        $delimPos = strripos($className, '\\');
        $className = substr($className, $delimPos + 1, strlen($className));
    }

    if (!class_exists($className)) {
        if (SYSTEM_DEBUG_MODE) {
            exit('Error: class not exists - ' . $className);
        }
        $error = 'System error! Please report to email: info@bit-changer.net';
        Lib_logger::saveToLog($error . ' (Class: '.$className.')', LOG_TYPE_ERROR_CRITICAL);
        exit($error);
    }
}
}


new Autoloader();
```

Comment: That `use lib\model as Lib;
class Bitgo implements Lib\BitcoinInterface` should be written like `use lib\model\BitcoinInterface ;
class Bitgo implements BitcoinInterface`

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't work. Autoloader get as $className 'BitcoinInterface' without namespace, and can't load it.